# Selenium IDE assertLocation

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to get my feet wet with Selenium IDE and I wanted to test the login process of the website that I work for. Once logged in you get a "newton" (its what my boss calls it) put in front of the members area of the website `http://abc1234.members.domain.tld` So I wanted to use `assertLocation` with a `glob:http://*.members.domain.tld` but I can't seem to get the syntax right or I'm just doing it plain wrong:

```
<tr>
<td>assertLocation</td>
<td>glob:http://*.members.domain.tld</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

but in the log I get:

```
[error] Actual value 'http://abc1234.members.domain.tld/' did not match 'glob:http://*.members.titanmen.com'
```

I tried all sorts of combinations of globs and regexs in various td fields even tried things like `assertLocation(glob:http://*.members.domain.tld)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And I see what I've mess up, no trailing slash `<td>assertLocation</td><td>glob:http://*.members.domain.tld/</td><td></td>`

Comment: Actually the log you posted showed you were lookgin for members.titanmen.com  but getting a location of members.domain.tld. But yes the trailing slash likely tripped you up.

Answer (score 0):

The `assertLocation` command will get current absolute address of the current page, which is `http://abc1234.members.domain.tld/` and compare it with pattern you entered in target, which is non-sensual `glob:http://*.members.domain.tld` and therefore the test-case is finished as failed.

The target should be most probably just `http://*.members.domain.tld/`